# How to parse str(my_datetime) using strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, strptime

This is the [default string representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__) of a datetime:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> dt = datetime(2017, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
>>> print(dt)
2017-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

What is the correct format string to parse that with `datetime.strptime`?  That is, what format goes in place of the "???" to consistently have the following invariant:

```
>>> dt == datetime.strptime(str(dt), "???")
True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `str(d)` is documented as being equivalent to [`d.isoformat(' ')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat). This starts with `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` (`2017-01-01 00:00:00`), but then:

- Either has nothing or `.%f`, depending whether the microseconds part is nonzero.
- Either has nothing or an offset like `+HH:MM`, depending whether the instance is timezone-aware.

`datetime.strptime` doesn't have support for optional parts, therefore there isn't a single `format` parameter that can match all of the possible outputs.

In Python 3.7+, you can use [`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0e06be836ca0d578cf9fc0c68979eb682c00f89c) to parse `datetime.isoformat` output. Contributed by Paul Ganssle in [issue15873](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873).

Comment: *Note:* one detail has become a little outdated, strptime %z supports colon in the offset now (new in Python 3.7)